# Bootstrap Multiselect scroll bar drag doesn't work in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, dropdown

I'm trying to use bootstrap multi-select in a bootstrap modal. I'm able to initialize it and render it perfectly no issues with that. I'm facing a really annoying issue wherein when I try to drag the scrollbar inside the modal the drop down closes. I tried and replicated the same code outside the bootstrap modal, it works perfectly. I've created the jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Normal scrolling works fine but dragging the scrollbar in the modal closes the drop-down. Any way to fix this issue?

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/darshanturakhia/hdnf9x61/5/)

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<select id="example-multiple-selected1" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
  <!-- Option 3 will be selected in advance ... -->
  <option value="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
  <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  <option value="5">Option 5</option>
  <option value="6">Option 6</option>
</select>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <select id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
          <!-- Option 3 will be selected in advance ... -->
          <option value="3" selected="selected">Option 3</option>
          <option value="4">Option 4</option>
          <option value="5">Option 5</option>
          <option value="6">Option 6</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('#example-multiple-selected').multiselect({
          maxHeight: 100
    });
    $('#example-multiple-selected1').multiselect({
          maxHeight: 100
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```
$('.modal').on('mousedown mouseup click', '.multiselect-container', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Working Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scooterlord/hdnf9x61/10/

Comment: Glad I could help